# RSS for DPDK is getting failed on QLogic FastLinQ QL4500010G/25G/40G/50G/100G Intelligent Ethernet Adapters (IEA) and Converged Network Adapters (CNA)

Tags: rss

[qede_rss_hash_update:2039(13:00.0:dpdk-port-0)]RSS hf = 0x104 len = 40 key = 0x7fffe5ea2370
[qede_rss_hash_update:2043(13:00.0:dpdk-port-0)]Enabling rss
[qede_rss_hash_update:2057(13:00.0:dpdk-port-0)]Applying user supplied hash key
[ecore_vf_pf_prep:35(13:00.0:dpdk-port-0-0)]preparing to send CHANNEL_TLV_VPORT_UPDATE tlv over vf pf channel

[ecore_send_msg2pf:101(13:00.0:dpdk-port-0-0)]VF -> PF [03] message: [00000002, d5db0340] --> 0x3630, 00000001 --> 0x3638
[QEDE PMD: (13:00.0:dpdk-port-0-0)]ecore_send_msg2pf:PF response: 3 [Type 3]
[ecore_vf_pf_req_end:61(13:00.0:dpdk-port-0-0)]VF request status = 0xfffffffd, PF reply status = 0x3
[qede_rss_hash_update:2085(13:00.0:dpdk-port-0)]vport-update for RSS failed
[qede_dev_start:1088(13:00.0:dpdk-port-0)]Device start fails
Fail to start port 0
Please stop the ports first
Done

Comment: question needs explanation and code view update edit